# Can't access media picker property in content node (Umbraco 7)

Tags: c#, html, razor, umbraco, media

I want to display my header logo on all pages from a master template, but I am having trouble getting the media URL from the document type.

My header logo resides in this content node: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7yTO.png

Which has the template set as master.

The document type for the page is located here in the tree: https://i.stack.imgur.com/28GrF.png

All my templates inherit from a single master template, where I want to display the header logo, but for some reason it won't display it when i insert the code for retrieving media items.

```
@{
  var typedMediaPickerSingle = Model.Content.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("headerLogo");
  if (typedMediaPickerSingle != null)
  {
    <a href="index.html"><img src='@typedMediaPickerSingle.Url" style="width:320px" alt="@typedMediaPickerSingle.GetPropertyValue("headerLogo")' /></a>
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get your content from a parent node don't use the current node  `Model.Content` but traverse the nodes like this:

```
var languageNode = Model.Content.AncestorOrSelf(2);
var typedMediaPickerSingle = languageNode.GetPropertyValue<IPublishedContent>("headerLogo");
```

The "2" in the AncestorOrSelf method is the level to want to reach.